# RSA keys generated on iOS won't work on Android

Tags: android, ios, encryption, rsa, x509

I'm generating keys on iOS using the following code

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 1024]
        var publicKeyPtr, privateKeyPtr: SecKey?
        let result = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &publicKeyPtr, &privateKeyPtr)
        print(result)

        let publicKey = publicKeyPtr!
        let privateKey = privateKeyPtr!

let encodedPublicKey = convertSecKeyToBase64(publicKey)!

func convertSecKeyToBase64(inputKey: SecKey) ->String? {
        // First Temp add to keychain
        let tempTag = "de.a-bundle-id.temp"
        let addParameters :[String:AnyObject] = [
            String(kSecClass): kSecClassKey,
            String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): tempTag,
            String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            String(kSecValueRef): inputKey,
            String(kSecReturnData):kCFBooleanTrue
        ]

        var keyPtr: AnyObject?
        let result = SecItemAdd(addParameters, &keyPtr)
        switch result {
        case noErr:
            let data = keyPtr! as! NSData

            // Remove from Keychain again:
            SecItemDelete(addParameters)
            let encodingParameter = NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)
            return data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(encodingParameter)

        default:
            print("Error: \(result)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

The encoded public key looks like this

```
MIGJAoGBAJZhrrBPuKvq8RuVPeg02D2iPahmVS9oomaqxITNcifBO6hhYomp4mlbubSWMYiHPbpeX7+gmG41B7E5BSJ7nHq7KZ9OMqiAekY5JhRmJlAhmKsBmjrSNbt0wqNXl3dxjj/sc1qauQBXY8X5fhEmatWDwvfb7nq/8yloPc5iAUalAgMBAAE=
```

When decrypting on Android, I get the error
 java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

Clearly the type of key being generated on iOS is not the type the Android code is looking for, how can I make iOS use the X509 type? Below is Android code

```
public static String encrypt(String text, Context c, String pub) {
        try {
            byte[] pubKey = Base64.decode(pub, 0);

            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKey);
            PublicKey key = factory.generatePublic(keySpec);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            for (int i = 0; i < (bytes.length / 128 + 1); i++) {
                int start = i * 128;
                int blockLength;
                if (i == bytes.length / 128)
                    blockLength = bytes.length - i * 128;
                else
                    blockLength = 128;
                if (blockLength > 0) {
                    byte[] encrypted = cipher
                            .doFinal(bytes, start, blockLength);
                    baos.write(encrypted);
                }

            }

            byte[] encrypted = baos.toByteArray();
            return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop the CryptoExportImportManager.swift file from below to your project. This will enable you to export the keys generated on iOS in PEM and DER formats which can be passed to Android and other platforms. The information in the README will explain more.

https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/CryptoExportImportManager

Answer (score 1):

I quote what Berin wrote in his [blog](http://blog.wingsofhermes.org/?p=42)

> First off, when you export a key from the iPhone keychain, it’s exported in a cut down format – just the public key and exponent without any of the other ASN.1 stuff you’d expect in a fully encoded public key. The java crypto functions generally expect a fully encoded key (OID and all).

In a word, the public key generated by `SecKeyGeneratePair` is not in a full format. In order to enable Android to use it, manual expansion is required. More can be found in that blog.

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME !, it keeps me frustated why everytime i googled about generating RSA in swift always fail in online RSA encryption and decryption.